# How to remove warning for the name "google" in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to figure out [the example of geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) and I have the following code in my event handler for a click on a button.

```
locate() {
  const coder = google.maps.Geocoder();
  coder.geocode(
    { address: "stockholm" }, 
    (result, status) => { ... });
}
```

It works as supposed to **but** the name *google* gets highlighted by VS Code with the warning that the name can't be found. I'm not sure where the object comes from and I don't know how to declare it so that it isn't flagged as unknown/undeclared.

When I run the `google` thingy in the console of Chrome, it actually does work producing some kind of object with maps in it. However, the same operation in the console of FireFox doesn't produce anything useful.

What's that googly-mappy object and how do I learn Angular that it's there?

Comment: It's provided by the inclusion of the Maps API script (the second script tag in the example).

Comment: @Amber Yeah, the thing is that I don't have that line in my Angular code at all. In fact, the **only** reference to *google* in any form is the second line in my sample. Also, it seems that Chrome know about it by default too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tell angular that a foreign JavaScript global object or lib is there by declaring it, as shown in previous answer:

```
declare const google: any;
```

You could also teach your typescript all the correct types so that VSCode will even help you:

```
npm install @types/googlemaps --save
```

Answer (score 1):

Under your imports you can tell the typescript compiler that there will be a global variable `google` at run time.

```
// component.ts
declare const google;
```